# Find largest index of nonzero in python

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I have a module to print ~12000 lists of 60 y values against a single set of 60 x values. Would like to find the largest x value that has a non-zero y value.
Using numpy np.nonzero(y) returns every list. Also tried

```
b = []
for i in range(len(y)):
    if y[i] != 0:  b.append(i)
print b
```

and it returned all 12000 indices in y.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Include a small example with the expected result, it makes understanding the question much easier.

Answer (score 2):

The `where` function returns a tuple, so you need to pull the first element to get at the data you want:

```
import numpy as np
y = [0, 0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0]
print np.where(y)[0].max()
```

This prints 7.

[Edit...]
I just re-read Adlai's question: He has a large list, each with 60 `x` values.  If everything is in lists, and one of the lists is very large, it's probably fastest to convert the 12000 item list of 60 values each to a 12000 by 60 array, and then just straight `numpy`.  If `y` is the "outside" list, then `np.array(y)` should come back with shape 12000, 60.  *If* that's the case, this is a better solution to finding which `x` values have somewhere a non-zero `y` value:

```
yy = np.array(y)  # results in a shape (12000, 60)
np.where((yy != 0).any(axis=0))[0]
```

The logic is: Convert your data to a truth table by comparing to zero, then collapse the truth table with `any(axis=0)`, then find the largest index in the collapsed truth table.

To pull it together with the `x` data, and wrap it up in a one-liner:

```
np.array(x)[np.where((np.array(y) != 0).any(axis=0))[0]].max()
```

This gives the largest `x` value that has *some* non-zero `y` value.  If you want an array of largest x-values corresponding to non-zero y-value, that would be a 12,000 item list of x-values (one for every set of 60 y-values), you need something slightly different.

Comment: thanks for the in depth response! i tried the fixes you recommend and returned the error
    `np.where((yy != 0).any(axis=0))[0]
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'any'`

Comment: Have a look at `type(yy)`.  It should be numpy.ndarray or maybe <class 'numpy.ndarray'> if you are using python3.  If `type(yy)` is list, you need to turn it into an array with `yy = np.array(yy)`.  The result of `yy != 0` should also be an numpy.ndarray.  Then, numpy.ndarray *does* have the property `.any()`.

Comment: It is also a good idea when you get an ndarray to check its size and type.  These are `yy.shape` and `yy.dtype`.  `yy.shape` should be your entire data set, something like (12000, 60) and `yy.dtype` should be a numeric type such as int64 or float.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np    
np.max(np.where(y))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [numpy.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

> Return elements, either from x or y, depending on condition.
>
> If only condition is given, return condition.nonzero().

Something like this:

```
largestindex = numpy.max(numpy.where(item))
```

Comment: This will not work. `array` and `numpy.max` are functions.  They are not the same, and the result of `array==numpy.max` always returns false.

Comment: I guess I ought to refresh the page more often when writing comments!